# How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows operating system?

Tags: windows-10

I want to disable automatic reboots in my windows operating system as it disrupts commands and sometimes even creates problem in programming

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Updates and set Active Hours so as to restart overnight when not using your machine (or your Active Hours to suit). Restarts will not occur until then.

Active Hours is the best approach. Combine with a notification of updates if you wish (I do) and then updates occur, pop up asks to wait to Off Hours, say OK and carry on working.

Also you can pause updates for a set number of days.

The key is to manage updates because they will occur and for most Windows license cannot be prevented.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to stop Windows Update.

In Windows 10: Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced Options > Turn off Restart this Device...
[image: Restart Option]
You could also just change your "Active Hours" to ensure a reboot happens when you are off the computer.

If you want something more forceful, you can open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Enable the option "No auto-restart with logged on users..."

[image]